# Running Wordpress in a subdirectory (not the root)

Tags: wordpress, .htaccess, directory

I have a wordpress site that is currently running in a subdirectory of my website, basically put my structure is as follows:
root/wp

I'd like to keep the wordpress wp folder in the same place however have it load the wordpress site directly from the root url.

For instance currently the site loads when I go to www.mysite.com/wp however I'd like to have the wordpress site load when I simply go to www.mysite.com - currently if I go to www.mysite.com it simply loads an 500 Internal Server Error message.

I would expect I'd need to make some changes to the htaccess files - can anyone suggest how this would be done

So in a nutshell
When I go to www.mysite.com - it looks at the /wp folder but still appears as www.mysite.com in the address bar.

Comment: Not work for me, I get "Internal Server Error".
In this case, what can I do?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Adding these lines to .htaccess should do the job (not tested, sorry, it may not be sufficient):

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(www.)?mysite.com$
RewriteRule ^(/)?$ wp [L]
```

**Update:** You might wish to check https://codex.wordpress.org/Giving_WordPress_Its_Own_Directory for a way to accomplish this that's closer to WordPress standards.

Comment: Just another quickie...
How would do this for a subdomain
eg RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(www.)?mysite.com$ 
But for admin.mysite.com so i'd not require the www at the start

Comment: @Gaz  `RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^((www|admin).)?mysite.com$` [NC] will work for `www` or `admin` subdomains