# Using wordpress in a subdirectory

Tags: wordpress, .htaccess

I use to have wordpress installed on the root of the website, but today I moved to a subdirectory "root/blog" with these steps:
1) Moved all the files>
2) Copied .htaccess and index.php do "root" and modify them
3) Change the wordpress URL on the settings.
It worked fine.
But I **don't want it be accessed via www.mysite.com.** I want to be access as www.mysite.com/blog. I want to do my own main index.
But if I remove the index.php from root, it gives me problems like /blog won't find my static first page.
What I'm missing?

Comment: You probably need to change the main apache configuration file.

Comment: Update your permalinks and make sure you changed the `home` and `siteurl` fields in the `wp_options` table.

Comment: Possible duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/43061554/wordpress-redirect-to-another-link/43061590 this link might help you too http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8742662/running-wordpress-in-a-subdirectory-not-the-root?rq=1

Comment: Thank you. It was a duplicate and the solution worked. I'm using a free webhost so I can't change apache config file. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You need to change your apache virtualhosts settings. 
More infos [here](https://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/en/vhosts/examples.html).